# Maven unable to find org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:1.5.8

Tags: java, spring, maven, version, spring-ws

When we try and use the org.springframework.wspring-ws as a dependency in a maven project thusly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

it is not found.  Looking at the [repo](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.ws%7Cspring-ws%7C1.5.8%7Cpom) the pom is there and so is the jar, but the jar has -all in the name like `spring-ws-1.5.8-all.jar`.

My questions:  First, how do I use this as a dependency in a maven pom?  Second, why is this file named this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though there is an accepted answer already, I still want to give some extra information on this, cause the accepted answer is providing something that may be incorrect.

You should not use the spring-ws-ver-all as dependency.  In Maven world, you should use the actual artifacts as dependencies instead (e.g. spring-ws-core etc).

One of the reason of not using such uber jar as dependency is, it may cause problem in dependency resolution.

For example, assume you are depending on 2 artifacts, A and B.  A have dependency to spring-ws-core version 1.0, B depends on spring-ws-core version 1.1.  Normally Maven will resolve to have only one version of spring-ws-core in your classpath.

However, if A is depending on spring-ws-all (which is the uber jar), Maven have no way to know that is spring-ws-all and spring-ws-core is something conflicting, and you will probably encounter problem because you have both classes from spring-ws 1.0 (from spring-ws-all) and 1.1 (from spring-ws-core).

Comment: From the example in the [tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html) it looks like you should use the core, rather than the all:`<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
    <classifier>all</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Not sure why they have that classifier.  Looks like there are no other classifiers for this lib, so no point really.
Looks like there are later version of this lib now: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws

And looks like they have rearranged things somewhat, so the classifier is prolly redundant for the latest version.

Comment: +1 I never use <classifier> inside <dependency> myself, this the correct solution for the question how. For second question about why, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

#### how do I use this as a dependency in a maven pom?

<strike>Go to your Maven local repository `~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws/1.5.8`, change jar file name to `spring-ws-1.5.8.jar`.</strike> **Use configuration mentioned in Lithium's answer,** Or use standalone module jars spring-ws-core, spring-ws-security, etc. instead of this all-in-one jar.

#### Why is this file named this way?

Check out source code [spring-ws/tags/spring-ws-1.5.8](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-ws/tags/spring-ws-1.5.8), it use maven-assembly-plugin ([pom.xml line 519](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-ws/tags/spring-ws-1.5.8/pom.xml?hb=true)) which use one assembly descriptor ([src/assembly/all.xml](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/spring-ws/tags/spring-ws-1.5.8/src/assembly/all.xml?hb=true)) to build final release, the <id>all</id> is appended to pom.version 1.5.8 as [classifier](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html#classifier).

<strike>I would consider this as a mistake in their build scripts.</strike>

Comment: This is also a correct answer but I can only mark one answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: I believe it is NOT a mistake.  It is intended instead.  spring-ws is a POM type project, and is used as multi-module project.  It is not appropriate to have its main artifact being a jar.  Using classifier (in assembly plugin) give the idea that it is "another form" of the project (which is reasonable as it is something aggregating all child projects).  And, renaming the JAR is absolutely a WRONG thing to do.

Comment: @AdrianShum, Basically agreed, however, this is not the normal way we should use to build release, as you can see, it sometimes confuse people. I will update my answer.

Comment: @yorkw I think it IS the normal way to build release in Maven world.  Normally in Maven we don't have those uber-JAR, coz dependencies can be resolved transitively.  Therefore, in a more Maven way, we shouldn't use such uber-jar as dependency. Use individual modules instead.  Using such uber-jar as dependency may cause problem transitive dependency resolution in the future. And, using assembly + classifier for such kind of uber-jar is so normal to denote that artifact is aimed for special purpose (e.g. an uber-jar that you may use it as dependency only when you know what you are doing).